# Querying Notification System with entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm developing an `MVC4` Application and i build a Notification system send news about seals to users that are subscribed companies so i save the last time the user have visit the site and the time when a sales has made and in the next time the user come back to the site i compere the user last time vised the site with all the products seals time and if the product seals time is bigger than last time visit for user it return all this product that specified this condition but i cant get the companies that the user is subscribed too to only get this product from this companies this is my data base:

[image: database]

and this what i'm trying to do in entity framework:

```
public ActionResult LastTimeVisedSales()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

   var UserCompaniesSubscribed = db.SubscribDetails.Include(sub => sub.User).Include(sub => sub.Company)
                                   .Where(sub => sub.UserID == CurrentUserID).ToList();

   var LastTimeVisetDate = db.UserProfiles.Where(p => p.UserID == CurrentUserID)
                             .Select(user => new
                              {
                             lastTimeViset = user.LastLogin
                              }).SingleOrDefault();

  var lastlogin = LastTimeVisetDate.lastTimeViset;

  List<ProductsIndexViewModel> Result = new List<ProductsIndexViewModel>();

      foreach(var d in UserCompaniesSubscribed){

         var ProductNewsLogIn = db.Products.Include(p => p.SubCategory).Include(p => p.Store)
                                .Where(p => p.SalesTime >= lastlogin && p.Store.Company.CompanyID == d.CompanyID )
                                .Select(p => new ProductsIndexViewModel
                                {
                                    ProductID = p.ProductID,
                                    ProductImageURL = p.ProductImageURL,
                                    ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                    Price = p.Price,
                                    Quantity = p.Quantity,
                                    Sales = p.Sales,
                                    Discount = p.Discount,
                                    NewPrice = p.NewPrice,
                                    StoreName = p.Store.StoreName,
                                    CategoryName = p.SubCategory.Category.CategoryName,
                                    SubCategoryName = p.SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
                                    CompanyName = p.Store.Company.CompanyName
                                }).SingleOrDefault();

                Result.Add(ProductNewsLogIn);
                }

            return Json(Result);
        }

        return Json("no seals from last time log in");
    }
```

and many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

basically, we find the last login date of the user using a simple query.
and then query all the products belonging to the stores housed by the companies, the user has subscribed to.

note that we can leverage EF's association to avoid joins.
also, if you use an associated entity in the where clause, then it is automatically available in the select clause. you don't need to do an explicit `Include`. e.g. p.Store below.

```
var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(up => up.UserID == CurrentUserID);

if (userProfile != null)
{
 var lastLoginDate = userProfile.LastLogin; 
 var companyIds = db.Companies.Where(c => c.UserID == CurrentUserID).Select(c => c.CompanyID);

 var productViewModels = db.Products.Include(p => p.SubCategory)
                                    .Join(companyIds, p => p.Stores.CompanyID, c => c, (p, c) => p) 
                                    .Where(p => p.SalesTime >= lastLoginDate)
                                    .Select(p => new ProductsIndexViewModel
                                     {
                                      ProductID = p.ProductID,
                                      ProductImageURL = p.ProductImageURL,
                                      ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                      Price = p.Price,
                                      Quantity = p.Quantity,
                                      Sales = p.Sales,
                                      Discount = p.Discount,
                                      NewPrice = p.NewPrice,
                                      StoreName = p.Store.StoreName,
                                      CategoryName = p.SubCategory.Category.CategoryName,
                                      SubCategoryName = p.SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
                                      CompanyName = p.Store.Company.CompanyName
                                     }).ToList();
}
```

we could even combine the whole of above into one giant query which also calculates the last login inline. whatever you prefer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.SalesTime > user.LastLogin && user.Companies.Contains(p.Store.Company));
```

**Caveats**

For questions like this, it's better if you post your POCOs as the table columns have very little in reality to do with the Entity Framework API you use to query. As a result, I'm making guesses about property names based on your column names and relationships. It assumes you have something like the following in your classes:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    // M2M between dbo.UserProfile and dbo.Companies through dbo.SubscribDetails
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Product
{
    // Foreign key to dbo.Stores via StoreID
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Store
{
    // Foreign key to dbo.Companies via CompanyID
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    ...
}
```